# Static container name when running Testcontainers with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, testcontainers

My application consists of a Spring Boot app and a database. I can successfully run them in Docker using docker-compose. I now want to use a similar Docker compose file along with testcontainers to write some automated tests. I am failing because the hostname in the application.yml file of the Spring Boot app doesn't match the random name assigned to the database container and therefore the app is unable to connect to the database.

### docker-compose

```
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    image: simon/api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    networks:
      - my_network

  api-db:
    image: simon/api-db:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    networks:
      - my_network

  networks:
    my_network:
      external: false
```

### Class rule set-up

```
@ClassRule public static DockerComposeContainer<?> dockerEnvironment =
        new DockerComposeContainer<>(new File("docker-compose.yml"))
                .withPull(false)
                .withLocalCompose(true)
                .withExposedService("api", "8080");
```

### application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: docker
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://api-db:5432/api
```

When the test runs, the containers are assigned names such as:

wtdopq2hneev_api_1
wtdopq2hneev_api-db_1

The fact that it seems to be assigning a random network name (wtdopq2hneev) rather than using my_network, is ultimately my problem.

I can specify the name of the container in the docker-compose.yml file, but then I can't 'expose' the services which I need to be able to so that I can call my API from my tests:

Am I going about this in the wrong way?

- Java version: 1.8.0_144
- Testcontainers version: 1.8.3
- Docker for Mac version: 17.09.0-ce-mac35 (19611)

The Docker version is a little old but I don't think that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

The container name shouldn't matter here, it's the hostname that is important, and in your case this will be `api` and `api-db`. For this simple use case there is probably no need for a custom network, did you try it without one?

Answer (score -1):

Just set a container name and then you will know it:

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: whatever-you-fancy
```

Comment: Yes I did mention in my question that I could do that which would resolve the database connectivity issue, but how do I then 'expose' the database? I want to do grey box testing, so I want to be able to query the database. I've described a simple example, but in the real world there are more services that need to connect to each other but at the same time I will want to connect to them from within my tests,

Comment: setting a container_name when using testcontainers results in an error.